# Symfony Service Configurator: getToken with security.context is NULL

Tags: symfony, security-context

I'm using Symfony Service Configurator in my project to configure a service after its instantiation ([Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/configurators.html)), 
in Configure method I need the current user logged so I inject the container and I tried to get the token form Security.context service but I got always NULL.
I tried also to inject only Security.context in my Configurator construct but I got same result.

Any ideas pls

Thanks.

```
class MyConfigurator
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }


    public function configure()
    {
        $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken();
        var_dump($user); // = NULL
    }
}
```

Comment: Are You logged in ??

Comment: @skowron-line yes I'm logged

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167979/authentication-token-always-null-in-kernel-request-event-in-symfony-2?rq=1 to see if it helps

Comment: @joaoalves thanks for your response but I'm not using a Listener to sent it with hight priority.

Comment: I suppose that your service is created early before security.context is populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve the problem by getting the UserId from the session and fetch the current User from Database.

The UserId is set previously by a AuthenticationListener in my project.
So I modify my Configurator construct to be like this:

```
    /**
     * @param EntityManager $em
     * @param Session $session
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, Session $session)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->session = $session;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way should be:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;

class MyConfigurator
{
     private $tokenStorage;

     public function __construct(EntityManager $em, TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
     {
         $this->em = $em;
         $this->tokenStorage= $tokenStorage;
     }

     public function configure()
     {
         $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
     }

     ....
```