# Retrieving security token in kernel response listeners

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I need to access the current user in a custom kernel response listener in the Symfony v4.2.1 application I'm working on. When I try to retrieve the token from the TokenStorage in the listener, i get null. From [what I read](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/22513), this is normal because the event occurs before Symfony security firewall is run but, as i desperately need to access the token in the listener, I wondered if there would be a workaround to do so. In previous versions, a workaround was to [play on priorities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167979/authentication-token-always-null-in-kernel-request-event-in-symfony-2) but i don't think it's possible anymore.

Here is the firewall configuration from security.yaml:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                #- App\Security\SSOAuthenticator
                 - App\Security\YesAuthenticator
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        logout: ~

        guard:
            authenticators:
                #- App\Security\SSOAuthenticator
                 - App\Security\YesAuthenticator
```

The route I'm having issue with is "/api/occurrences". Here is the relevant part from a debug:route command:

```
  api_occurrences_get_collection   GET      ANY      ANY    /api/occurrences.{_format}
```

It is automatically assigned by the framework I use, API platform, based on the entity class name (Occurrence ).

Here are the priorities for the relevant event:

```
"kernel.response" event
-----------------------

 ------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
  Order   Callable                                                                                     Priority  
 ------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
  #1      App\EventListener\MyResponseListener::onKernelResponse()                                 0         
  #2      ApiPlatform\Core\Hydra\EventListener\AddLinkHeaderListener::onKernelResponse()               0         
  #3      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse()              0         
  #4      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelResponse()          0         
  #5      Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse()              0         
  #6      Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelResponse()       0         
  #7      ApiPlatform\Core\HttpCache\EventListener\AddHeadersListener::onKernelResponse()              -1        
  #8      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse()              -100      
  #9      Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse()   -128      
  #10     Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelResponse()               -1000     
  #11     Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse()      -1024     
 ------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
```

**EDIT**

After some more tests, i realized this only happens when i call the Web service via the browser. If using curl e.g. the token is successfully retrieved. So I guess it seems the issue is not related to Symfony core but to the interaction between API framework platform and my custom security setup.

Comment: A kernel response listener is called before the firewall? How is that technically possible? You need a firewall to generate a response that is afterwards listened to by a response listener. The problem might be something else...

Comment: I based this assertion on Stoph's reply in the github issue the first link in my question refers to : "it can return null if your method is not behind the firewall (or if you call it before the firewall ran, either in CLI, in an early kernel.request listener or a kernel.response or kernel.exception listener for early exception). "

Comment: Just a quick comment: listener priorities are still very much a thing.  You appear to have something else going on but you can dump out the listeners and check their priorities.

Comment: Cerad, I added the relevant priorities to my question and it appears the custom listener comes first. Still, i can get the token without any problem if the Web service is called from curl.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security` class instead of the TokenStorage?

After that just use `$this->security->getUser()` with security being autowired in the constructor.

If that didn't help you out let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem: the returned value is null...

Comment: Please share your firewall configuration so we can have a further look.

Comment: I created a Gist for you, https://gist.github.com/cirykpopeye/64f2e8b8718213723ac72dbc8abddedc This shows a subscriber doing what you want. Should be the same principle as an event listener. If your firewall is correct this should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example. I should have added that this is not an issue with every event listener, only the kernel response one: some other listeners are setup in the app (for preUpdate and prePersist Doctrine events) and the current user token can be retrieved without any problem from those.

Comment: That means it's not your firewall. Which events are you listening for? https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events/ has a few examples.

Comment: The listener is setup to listen to "event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse". And you're right, the issue is not firewall related as such but must result from the interaction of my custom security setup with API plaform (see my edited question). Investigating this.

Comment: Could you try as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52276465/access-current-user-in-the-kernel-events-symfony-4? First check if the token is null, and if it isn't proceed to fetch the user?

Comment: Ciryk Popeye, I can do this to avoid getting an exception but i do need access to the token in the listener so discarding it is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

If the token storage returns null, that probably means the url you are currently trying it on, is not included in a firewall or that the user is not authenticated. (*Unauthenticated requests have an null value token*)

Do you mind sharing your security configuration and the routing part of the application you are struggling with?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I had already checked this based on the info in the first link in my question. Please see the updated question. The user is authenticated. I can tell so because the returned JSON response I'm trying to add HTTP headers to in my listener is built based on the current user the token.